# What is the C# equivalent of Perl's repetition operator?

Tags: c#, perl, string

In Perl

```
print "a" x 3;  # aaa
```

In C#

```
Console.WriteLine( ??? )
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends what you need... there is `new string('a',3)` for example.

For working with strings; you could just loop... not very interesting, but it'll work.

With 3.5, you could use `Enumerable.Repeat("a",3)`, but this gives you a sequence of strings, not a compound string.

If you are going to use this a lot, you could use a bespoke C# 3.0 extension method:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string foo = "foo";
        string bar = foo.Repeat(3);
    }
    // stuff this bit away in some class library somewhere...
    static string Repeat(this string value, int count)
    {
        if (count < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value; // GIGO            
        if (count == 0) return "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length * count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(value);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Marc dont you think StringBuilder().Insert(0, value, count) is better?

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to repeat a single character (as in your example) then this will work:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string('a', 3))
```

Comment: True, but it fulfills the requirement in the question.

Comment: So Perl's repetition operator works only on chars? The fact that he used a string comprising of a single character shouldn't have tipped you off to restrict the answer to that particular example. The question was more general.

Comment: See my other reply for how to do this with strings then.

Answer (score 5):

Well in all version of .NET to repeat a string you could always do this

```
public static string Repeat(string value, int count)
{
  return new StringBuilder().Insert(0, value, count).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to do this with strings like Tom pointed out, then an extension method will do the job nicely.

```
static class StringHelpers
{
    public static string Repeat(this string Template, int Count)
    {
        string Combined = Template;
        while (Count > 1) {
            Combined += Template;
            Count--;
        }
        return Combined;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "abc";
        Console.WriteLine(s.Repeat(3));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: For work in a loop like this, it would be adviseable to use StringBuilder... concatenation is fine for 2-or-3, but if somebody asks for "a".Repeat(100) you have a lot of unnecessary strings to collect.

Comment: That's true.  There is some point in which StringBuilder becomes more efficient.  I've heard that it's around 10.  In the example given he had 3, so I assumed it would be small.  If you want to cover a wider range, then putting in an "if" and using StringBuilder for over 10 would be more efficient.